# Rails view help renders wrong partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having that problem that I am getting the wrong partial rendered.

Instead of rendering the partial that is located in `kategoris/_konkurrencer`

It is rendering the partial in `public/_konkurrencer`

My action:

```
def fast
  @titel = 'asdasd'
  @konkurrancer = Konkurrancer.where('type', 'nyhedsbrev')
  render 'kategoris/show'
end
```

My rails log:

```
Rendered public/_konkurrencer.html.erb (25.0ms)
Rendered shared/_rating.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered shared/_google_analytics.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered kategoris/show.html.erb within layouts/kategori (103.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 231ms (Views: 139.0ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

And my `kategoris/show` view file:

```
<%= render 'konkurrencer', :remote => true %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the directory name:

```
<%= render 'kategoris/konkurrencer', :remote => true %>
```

Ps. You probably have a good reason to have a partial in the public folder?

Comment: Yes I use my public konkurrencer partial to my index view file

Comment: How do I find all konkurrencer where the form is Nyhedsbrev? I have tried this: Konkurrencer.where('form', 'Nyhedsbrev')

Comment: I have found the solution: Konkurrancer.where(type: nyhedsbrev)

Comment: Yes Zabba it did I will approve your answer :)